# Modify default "dismiss" behavior of Bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The way the Bootstrap modal JS is written, a click event anywhere within the ".modal" element will dismiss the modal. On any and all children of the ".modal" class, the dismiss behavior is disabled, allowing the user to interact with the modal's content.

My question - how could I modify this behavior slightly so that clicking children of ".modal" will dismiss it, but clicking children of children will not?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="foo"><!--dismiss modal on click-->
        <div class="bar"><!--don't dismiss modal on click-->
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x800"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this instance, the desired behavior is that a click on ".foo" should dismiss the modal while a click on ".bar" would NOT dismiss the modal, and go about its usual business.

The reason for this is I am doing some advanced positioning and need two wrapper elements around the actual modal content, which will both still dismiss the modal when clicked upon.

See the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8w7fxtyr/

Comment: This was an interesting problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pair of delegated handlers should do the trick, and you only need to set them up once, not per-modal: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w7fxtyr/2/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".modal .bar", false);
$(document).on("click", ".modal .foo", function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
});
```

Note that the order is important, we need to ignore clicks on `.bar` before we act on clicks on `.foo`.

Or if avoiding the use of the `.foo` and `.bar` classes is important, you can do it with child selectors: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w7fxtyr/3/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".modal > * > *", false);
$(document).on("click", ".modal > *", function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add standard data-dismiss attribute to the `foo` element:

```
<div class="foo" data-dismiss="modal">
```

but prevent click propagation further than `bar`:

```
$(".modal .bar").on("click", function () { return false; });
```

Comment: Side note: jQuery has as shorthand for `function() { return false; }` handlers, which is simply `false`: `.on("click", false)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works, and you don't need to specify any classes other than .modal so it remains extensible.

```
$(".modal > *").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().modal('hide');
}).children().click(function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Problem is, you have to do it for each and every modal, rather than one fire-and-forget.

Comment: Why would I have to do it for every modal? The .modal class is generic and will be used on every modal.

Comment: Dynamically-added modals. I've updated my answer to avoid `.foo` and `.bar` if that's important.